# Element stale or not clickable errors in selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

As a forewarning, I am very new to writing code and just picked it up as a hobby so, apologies if my lingo is off.

I wrote some code to navigate to a web page and then refresh that page over and over again until a certain element (currently a class) appears and then click on that class.  I do not need help with the website navigation portion (other questions and answers on this site were very helpful to figure out sticking points in that process), but I often get error messages when the element finally appears and selenium tries to click on the element.  I see a few different error messages, including:

- The element reference of h4 class="start" is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed; or
- Element  is not clickable at point (706,145) because another element li class="loading-wrapper loading" obscures it.

Here is the relevant portion of the code:

```
i = 0
while i == 0:
    if len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("start")) == 0:
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("active.day").click() #this just refreshes the page
        time.sleep(0.1)
        continue
    else:
        break
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='start' and starts-with(text(), '7')]")[0].click()
```

And here is an example of a relevant portion of the website before the "start" element I am trying to click appears:

```
<div id="content" class="row">

    <ul id="times" class="col-md-12"> 

        <li class="time empty muted">

            <h1>No tee times available</h1>

            <p>Booking for 8/09/2020 starts at 7:00pm (PDT)</p>

        </li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

And here is an example of a relevant portion of the HTML after the "start" element I am trying to click appears:

```
  <div class="reserve-time">
    
    <div class="pull-left">

        <h4 class="start">7:38am</h4>
        
        <div class="holes" style="margin-right: 0.5em;">

            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></i> <span class="holes">18</span>

        </div>
        
        <div class="spots">
            
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> <span class="spots">3</span>
        
         </div>
        
    </div>

    <div class="pull-right">

        <div class="price">
            
            <span title="Green Fee">

            <i class="icon-golf-ball-tee" style="font-size: 1em;"></i>

            $33.00

        </span>
            
        </div>

    </div>
    
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

P.S. - I hope the HTML shows up okay in the post.  I am having trouble copying the HTML into the post and having it show up.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium cannot click an object it cannot see - just like you cannot click something on a webpage that you cannot see. When debugging Selenium code, what I do is add a "sleep" for 10 minutes just before the line that crashes. Then, in the open browser, I see if the element I'm trying to click is accessible.

In your case, it sounds like there's a loading screen obscuring it. I recommend instead of using explicit sleeps (`time.sleep(0.1)`), you use `webdriver.implicitly_wait(10)` to wait up to 10 seconds for an element to become visible. If that doesn't work, consider the debugging method above, where you actually try it out in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can wait till the element is visible, once it is visible then you can click on the element. The below code will help you achieve that.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

Start_Element = wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h4[@class='start']")))
Start_Element.click()
```

Comment: When the start element appears there will be 10-20 of them.  Is it possible to do the wait until the element is visible for a specific one of them?  For example, when I click on the element, I click on the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. by adding a [0], [1], [2] to the end of my driver.find_elements line, like so: driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='start' and starts-with(text(), '6')]")[0].click()